# Invoking manual sync of Azure App Services via webhook is failing with 401 error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to invoke the Azure App Service sync function via a HTTP call rather than Azure PowerShell to for a git pull and update.

From what I understand this should be achievable by calling

```
https://[sitename]:[sitepasswd]@[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/deploy
```

with a json payload of

```
{ 
    "format": "basic", 
    "url": "https://github.com/[gituser]/[repo]"
}
```

This call is however failing with a LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Request failed with status code: 401 exception. Specifying a github username and password in the request does not resolve the issue.

Syncing via portal and PowerShell works fine, so I assume I'm missing a parameter somewhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The scm site uses single sign on, so if you're already logged on to the Azure portal, you will be able to go directly to it without typing additional credentials. Sync via portal and powershell which us your user credential to login.

If you prefer not to use Single Sign On and instead use `basic auth`, you can go to `http://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/basicauth`. The scm service will prompt you for credentials. Here, you can use either the `user publishing credentials` (same as you use for git), or the `site level credentials`. See [Deployment-credentials](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) for details.

Comment: Is there a way to pass creds so that I can just call the /deploy API directly?